# How to get jar library name and version from String library name?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have many jar files in my directory:

- some-lib-2.0.jar
- some-lib-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- some-lib-3.RELEASE.jar
- some-lib-R8.jar
- some-lib-core-1.jar
- some-lib-2.patch2.jar
- some-lib-2-alpha-4.jar
- some-lib.jar
- some-lib2-4.0.jar

How can I get library name and version from file name?

Is regex ((?:(?!-\d)\S)+)-(\S*\d\S*(?:-SNAPSHOT)?).jar$ valid for extract name and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number in the JAR file name is merely a convention and a default for Maven-built JARs.  It may have been overridden, and it is not always reliable reading the version number from just the file name.

A more reliable way for reading version number from JAR is to look inside the JAR file.  Here you have a couple of options depending on how the JAR was built:

- look at `META-INF/maven/.../pom.properies` and `pom.xml` and read the version from that - this should be present for Maven-built binaries
- sometimes version number if present in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF under `Specification-Version` or `Implementation-Version` properties

If this fails, then fall back to reading version number from the JAR name since there is no other information available.

Answer (score 0):

Naming policy could differ across different libraries, so you aren't able to extract name/version from package name using one rule, for details you should check project docs.

In case of Maven you are able to configure the final name of built artifact with `finalName` `pom.xml` configuration option. Maven docs provide nice [introduction](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) into pom structure. Below is the example from docs:

```
<build>
    ...
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    ...
</build>
```